# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray: error when calling webservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have this service class where I am trying to fetch data returned from SQL query into JSONArray which in turn I am returning to the controller, on calling this web service, I am getting the above error, can anyone tell, where I have made a mistake.

```
package oal.crm.apps.territories.qaudit1.services.impl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import oal.crm.apps.territories.qaudit.utils.DbCalls;
import oal.crm.apps.territories.qaudit1.services.AuditSummaryService;

@Service
public class AuditSummaryServiceImpl implements AuditSummaryService{
    
    DbCalls db = new DbCalls();
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;    
    PreparedStatement statement1 = null;    
    ResultSet rs = null;    
    JSONArray JSONObjectArray = null;

    @Override
    public JSONArray getSummaryGroupByTopNode(Long batchId) {
        
        String top_node;
        Long current_issue_cnt;
    
        try {
            
            con = db.getDbConnection();
            
            String query1 = "SELECT top_node, count(1) CURRENT_ISSUE_CNT FROM q_audit_results where batch_id = ? GROUP BY top_node";

            statement1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
            statement1.setLong(1, batchId);
            rs = statement1.executeQuery(query1);
            JSONObjectArray = new JSONArray();

            while (rs.next()) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
                top_node = rs.getString(1);
                current_issue_cnt = rs.getLong(2);
                
                if (top_node == null) {
                    jsonobject.put("TOP_NODE", "");

                } else {
                    jsonobject.put("TOP_NODE", top_node);

                }
                
                jsonobject.put("CURRENT_ISSUE_CNT", current_issue_cnt);

                JSONObjectArray.put(jsonobject);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return JSONObjectArray; 
    }
}
```

**--Service Interface**

```
@Service
public interface AuditSummaryService {
    
    public JSONArray getSummaryGroupByTopNode(Long batchId);

}
```

**--Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("summary")
@Log4j2
public class AuditSummaryController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuditSummaryService auditSummaryService;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/topNode/batchId/{batchId}")
    public JSONArray getSummaryByNode(@PathVariable final Long batchId) {
        log.info("Starting getSummaryByNode method");
        return auditSummaryService.getSummaryGroupByTopNode(batchId);
    }
    
}
```

java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray: error on calling was via postman

Comment: where is that exception thrown

Comment: in postman error status: 500

Comment: postman doesn't throw Exceptions, it just shows you the result.